# Error while inserting data into partitioned external table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql, parquet

I have been trying to achieve dynamic partitions in a hive external table. I have some parquet files in Azure Data Lake gen2 file systems(HDFS supported). I have followed below steps:

1. Create a temporary external table (path : tempdata has parquet files)

```
create external table temp(a string, b string,c double,d double) 
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION 'abfs://xyz@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/wheeler/tempdata';
```

2. Set hive properties

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
```

3. Create partitioned external table (path :partitiontabledata is empty)

```
create external table external_dynamic_partitions(a string,c double) 
partitioned by (b string,d double) 
LOCATION 'abfs://xyz@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/wheeler/partitiontabledata;
```

4. Load data to external table with partitions from source file

```
insert overwrite table external_dynamic_partitions partition(b,d) 
select * from temp;
```

But its giving me some error in last step(4). I am attaching few lines of error here. Please help.

```
INFO  : Query ID = hive_20190910113348_da88325c-8551-4dac-ab34-8e02d5aeadf6
INFO  : Total jobs = 1
INFO  : Launching Job 1 out of 1
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-1:MAPRED] in serial mode
INFO  : Subscribed to counters: [] for queryId: hive_20190910113348_da88325c-8551-4dac-ab34-8e02d5aeadf6
INFO  : Session is already open
INFO  : Dag name: insert overwrite table p...battery_data_test (Stage-1)
INFO  : Tez session was closed. Reopening...
INFO  : Session re-established.
INFO  : Session re-established.
INFO  : Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1567683428701_0013)

ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1567683428701_0013_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1567683428701_0013_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567683428701_0013_1_00_000000_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter$LongDataWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter$GroupDataWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter$MessageDataWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.write(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.write(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:31)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:128)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.write(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.write(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:993)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:555)
    ... 20 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1567683428701_0013_1_00_000000_1:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.toErrorMessage(MapOperator.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableLongObjectInspector.get(WritableLongObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter$LongDataWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter$GroupDataWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter$MessageDataWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriter.write(DataWritableWriter.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.write(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.write(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:31)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:128)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:182)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.write(ParquetRecordWriter.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.write(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.write(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:993)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.baseForward(Operator.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:940)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:555)
    ... 20 more
.......
```

I have followed the below link for all the steps.
[creating partition in external table in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580356/creating-partition-in-external-table-in-hive?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got `ClassCastException`
Table in which you inserting has `a string,  c double, b string,d double` types
And you inserting                `a string,  b string, c double, d double`
Try to cast or change table DDL.

Or if you want to bind columns by names, this does not work in Hive. The order of columns should be the same in the select and in the table you inserting. Binding is positional.

Like this:

```
insert overwrite table external_dynamic_partitions partition(b,d) 
select a, c, b, d from temp;
```

In this case column types will match.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried this but still while writing into parquet files, its trying to cast double to long and during this its throwing exception. I am wondering why its doing this conversion automatically?